# The factorization of B could not be completed and no eigenvalues or eigenvectors were computed

Tags: python, matrix, linear-algebra, eigenvalue, eigenvector

I'm trying to solve the eigenvalue equation, *A x = λ B x* with *A* and *B* as 16×16 square Hermitian matrices. Using the linalg library on python (Spyder4) and I got an error saying:

> ```
> LinAlgError: The leading minor of order 12 of B is not positive definite.  
>              The factorization of B could not be completed and no eigenvalues or eigenvectors were computed.
> ```

here is the matrix and the command I used:

```
H = np.array([[a11,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,a19,a110,a111,a112,a113,a114,a115,a116] 
              [0,a22,0,0,0,0,0,0,a29,a210,a211,a212,a213,a214,a215,a216],
              [0,0,a33,0,0,0,0,0,a39,a310,a311,a312,a313,a314,a315,a316],
              [0,0,0,a44,0,0,0,0,a49,a410,a411,a412,a413,a414,a415,a416], 
              [0,0,0,0,a55,0,0,0,a59,a510,a511,a512,a513,a514,a515,a516],
              [0,0,0,0,0,a66,0,0,a69,a610,a611,a612,a613,a614,a615,a616], 
              [0,0,0,0,0,0,a77,0,a79,a710,a711,a712,a713,a714,a715,a716], 
              [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,a88,a89,a810,a811,a812,a813,a814,a815,a816], 
              [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,a99,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], 
              [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,a1010,0,0,0,0,0,0], 
              [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,a1111,0,0,0,0,0], 
              [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,a1212,0,0,0,0], 
              [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,a1313,0,0,0], 
              [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,a1414,0,0], 
              [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,a1515,0], 
              [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,a1616]])  

S = np.array([[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,b19,b110,b111,b112,b113,b114,b115,b116], 
              [0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,b29,b210,b211,b212,b213,b214,b215,b216],
              [0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,b39,b310,b311,b312,b313,b314,b315,b316],
              [0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,b49,b410,b411,b412,b413,b414,b415,b416], 
              [0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,b59,b510,b511,b512,b513,b514,b515,b516],
              [0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,b69,b610,b611,b612,b613,b614,b615,b616], 
              [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,b79,b710,b711,b712,b713,b714,b715,b716], 
              [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,b89,b810,b811,b812,b813,b814,b815,b816], 
              [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], 
              [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0], 
              [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0], 
              [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0], 
              [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0], 
              [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0], 
              [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0], 
              [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]])

lamda, x = lg.eigh(H, S, lower=False, eigvals_only=False)
print("Eigenvalues")   
print(lamda)
```

The variables in the matrix are user inputs (Some -ve values, and complex numbers).

The eigenvalue is computed when I use "`linalg.eig`" command but since my actual matrix is symmetric, I'm trying to use eigh command.

Has anybody faced this problem and/or suggest what the error is about?
Thanks

Comment: Please paste the code with the actual numbers you're using to compute so others can reproduce the error and try to correct it.

Comment: Are your matrices Hermitian? is, e.g.,  `H[15,0] == conjugate(H[0,15])`? if I trust not what you say but the code you've posted, `H[15,0]` is zero, and `H[0,15]` is `a116`, some "user input" that can be whatever number the "user" is dreaming of… If I'm right, it's no surprise that the algorithm for generic matrices work, and the one for Hermitian matrices fails.

Comment: Yes you are right @gboffi, the matrix H doesn't appear hermitian, but my actual matrix is hermitian, i.e the lower left 8*8 matric is conjugate of upper right 8*8 matrix. But in the code I put the entries of lower left matrices 0 because the "linalg.eigh" command only takes the upper half of the matrix and assumes the matrix is hermitian. The error doesn't seem to be in the individual matrices because, it gives the eigen values of H and S matrix with out error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation says that the second argument must be a complex Hermitian or a real symmetric definite positive matrix.  If your `b` are complex, that it appears that this argument is neither.

The documentation also says that this method throws a `LinAlgError`:

> If eigenvalue computation does not converge, an error occurred, or b
> matrix is not definite positive. Note that if input matrices are not
> symmetric or Hermitian, no error will be reported but results will be
> wrong.

Comment: The problem was that the matrices weren't Hermitian. My 'b's and 'a's are complex entries, but H and S weren't hermitian.  When I made both H and S hermitian, the eigen values were computed. I was assuming the linalg.eigh would make the matrix hermitian by only considering the upper half of the matrix, but it seems it is only for a real symmetric matrix.
Thank You.